# Is there a way to have a Global Timer in C#? One that can be used on multiple forms

Tags: c#

My app is a quiz with around 6 forms, and currently. I have a global variable called "Time Taken" and a timer in every form that adds one to it every second and displays it.

I was wondering if there was a better way to do this so that i wouldn't need so much code.

For example, Maybe there is a way to write a global method(inside my static 'globals class' That can be called something like "Start Quiztime" and it will start the timer and add one to it throughout the whole program and update the label that has time in it every second.

I am using the .NET Framework 4.6.1

Comment: Did you use System.Windows.Forms.Timer ? To use a timer outside a windows form component you can use [System.Timers.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: So what happened when you tried to implement the solution you described?  Did it work?  If not, what about it wasn't working, specifically?

Comment: I don't know how to implement the solution i described

Comment: If you have 6 forms, each of which has a timer that adds 1 second to your global variable, you probably end up with the wrong elapsed time. Best is to remember the start time in a global variable and use the difference between DateTime.Now and the start time to get the elapsed time since quiz start.

Comment: Note how most apps you use every day have only one main window.  So instead of 6 forms, consider 1 form and 6 usercontrols.  Problem solved.

Comment: Even better than calculating time differences, you can use the `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` class. Generate an instance, `Start()` it, and using the `Elapsed`property you get a `TimeSpan` object with the elapsed time.

Answer (score 0):

There are no global variables in C#, there are static variables and yes, it is a correct usage case of static variables. However, you cannot rely on timers to calculate the time which is taken to complete the test.

Instead, you can create a static variable like `StartTime` and then validate current time against it. Something like:

```
public static class CurrentTest
{
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
}

// start test
CurrentTest.StartTime = DateTime.Now;
CurrentTest.EndTime = CurrentTest.StartTime.AddMinutes(15);  // 15 minutes for test

// inside timer loop on your forms
if (CurrentTest.EndTime <= DateTime.Now)
{ 
    // test is over
} else {
    timeleftLabel.Text = (CurrentTest.EndTime - DateTime.Now).ToString();
}
```

What is even better - you could create an instance of a test attempt and pass it through all of your forms to get rid of static value and make your code better.

Comment: I would argue that you can't rely on timers, but instead use DateTime.Now. Local computer time can be corrected, manually changes or winter/summer time change happen. You can get 2 identical DateTime.Now, even when 1 hour passed between those measurements. DateTime.UtcNow is slightly better, but it won't protect from manual date/time change or windows time synchronization.